# connectWithResult method is undefined for MqttClient object

Tags: mqtt, paho

Below are my imports used in my java program. What I am trying to do is, to create a `client` of type `MqttCient` and then use the method `connectWithResuls` as follows

```
client.connectWithResult(opts);
```

the problem is eclipse underscores the lie mentioned above with red squiggle, and I do not know why, I also referred to `Paho java docs` [here](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/index.html).

please let me know why the aforementioned method is not recognised.

**Imports**

```
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttPersistenceException;
```

Comment: Where did you get the library containing you paho library? It sounds like you may have a older version than the doc.

Comment: @hardillb kindly please can you provide the website o the most recent paho java library?. Though, i do not think it is because of the library, because I used the same library in one of my projects in the same work space and in the java program i have access to ConnectWithResults() method

Comment: @hardillb hi, maybe this could be a question for you :)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397417/how-to-use-the-un-blocking-method-of-mqttclient